# Heroku Websockets: cannot connect to server

Tags: python, heroku, websocket

I followed [Heroku's guide to using its websockets](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python)  to implement a real-time chat app using Python, Flask, redis, and Heroku. However, I none of the messages that I enter appear in the designated div container. When I check the console from firefox firefly, I constantly get

```
cannot connect to ws://host_url/submit server
cannot connect to ws://host_url/receive server
```

You can see the same error from [Heroku's official demo](http://flask-chat.herokuapp.com/) as well. I even clone the provide [github repository](https://github.com/heroku-examples/python-websockets-chat/blob/master/chat.py), but it also had the same error, and none of the messages appeared. I am not sure if there is a problem with Heroku, or I have some misunderstanding. Could anyone give me some guidance?

Comment: hmm you did enable the websocket addon by running: heroku labs:enable websockets ?

Comment: Yes, and I restarted the server as well.

Comment: Heroku's official demo isn't working for me either. Here's the error I get in Google Chrome: `WebSocket connection to 'ws://flask-chat.herokuapp.com/receive' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Connection' header value is not 'Upgrade': Upgrade`